# How to scroll a list of tags from the first to the last using XPATH?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, jdom

I am absolutly new in **XML Parsing** and in **XPATH query** in Java and I have the following problem:

I have the following XML file on which I have to do some queries:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>

  <status>
    <id>0</id>
    <message />
  </status>

  <objectList>
    <object id="obj1">
      <property1>value</property1>
      <property2>value</property2>
      <property3 />
    </object>

    <object id="obj2 ">
      <property1>value</sproperty1>
      <property2>value</property2>
      <property3>value</property3>
    </object>

    <object id="obj3 ">
      <property1>value</sproperty1>
      <property2>value</property2>
      <property3>value</property3>
    </object>

  </objectList>
</root>
```

The first thing that I have to do is take the value inside the unique **`<id>0</id>`** tag and I have do it using the following XPATH query (and this query work well):

```
XPath xPath = XPath.newInstance("s:Envelope/s:Body");
xPath.addNamespace("s", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");


org.jdom.Element objectElement = (Element) xPath.selectSingleNode(documentXML);
System.out.println("objectElement: " + objectElement);
```

(where **documentXML** contains the previous XML document)

This work well and put inside my **objectElement** object the value 0 that is inside the **`<id>0</id>`** tag.

Ok,
now I have to perform a more complex operation (and I have no many ideas about how do it) that is the following one:

As you can see I have a tag named **objectList** that contains 3 tag named **object** that represent a list of 3 Java objects having some some properties (**property1**, **property2** and **property3** that will be 3 variables into the related Java objectt)

Now I have to perform the following operations: **for each object tag inside the XML document create a new Java object and put the property subtag value inside the related value in the new Java object**

The problem is that I have no idea about scroll through the list of obecjt tags that areinside my
 tag (from the first to the last)

Some idea? Someone can help me to do it?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: XPath is wrong you want to select all the objectList/object nodes with an id attribute, and then you can do a foreach on them. e.g. /root/objectlist/object[@id]

Comment: ok but...how can I know the number of the <object> tags that are inside the <objectList> tag?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson or maybe I have not understand what are you say me?

Answer (score 1):

As @TonyHopkinson pointed out you use the expath expression `/root/objectlist/object[@id]`
and then use `selectNodes()` mothod insead of `selectSingleNode()`. The former returns a list you can iterate over.

Comment: mmm no it don't work as I want, because it create me a list of node but this list have the following shape: objectsList: [[Element: <object/>], [Element: <object/>]] It seems that take only the external <object> tag but not its content :-(

Comment: The content is in there, you just need another Xpath expression, e.g "property1" which you do from the each one in the list.